# Has any research been done on stair tread shape?

Tags: safety, stairs

I'm replacing the treads on a short flight of stairs, and have a CNC router available. Since this is my personal home, and there are only four treads on this stair, I'm considering custom shapes for the treads.

I know that a rounded edge resists damage and reduces damage from falling, and that a square edge is better for traction, reducing the probability of slipping and falling, but as anyone done any research on the comparative advantages of edge shape? Specifically, I'm wondering if anyone has done actual studies, and have they considered a rounded lip on the edge.

Comment: Does not matter much if your home or not, you need to go by code for size.  My opinion only, if feeling(blind, pitch dark) your way down steps, a square edge is probably easier to feel.  Probably does not help if wearing steel toe boots.  I think most of the difference between round and square will come from what you think looks nicer.

Comment: If you are not wearing hard shoes inside, then the wear is not going to too different between them.  I would go for square - for safety, from personal experience.